# File upload field conflict with fields with ajax callback

Tags: ajax

I'm having a problem with my form with fields having ajax callback.

I have a dropdown field with ajax callback and a file field that accepts csv file. Whenever I try to upload a file on that file field, it is resetting the value of my dropdown field.

Can someone help me in fixing this problem?

Thank you.

```
function mymodule_form_node_campaign_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){

if (isset($form['field_camp_location'])) {
        $form['field_camp_location']['widget']['#ajax'] = array(
        'callback' => 'location_change_callback1',
        'event' => 'change',
        );
    }
$form['field_camp_location']['widget']['#options'] = populate_location1_options($form, $form_state);

    if(isset($form_state->getValue('field_camp_location')[0])){
        $lid1 = $form_state->getValue('field_camp_location')[0];
        \Drupal::logger('LID1 VALUE')->notice('Content: '. print_r($lid1, TRUE));
    }else{
        $lid1 = array();
    }
}

function location_change_callback1($form, $form_state){

    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand("#edit-field-camp-location-wrapper", ($form['field_camp_location']))); //test
    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand("#edit-field-camp-cid-wrapper", ($form['field_camp_cid'])));   
    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand("#edit-field-camp-location2-wrapper", ($form['field_camp_location2'])));
    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand("#edit-field-camp-cid2-wrapper", ($form['field_camp_cid2'])));
    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand("#edit-field-camp-location3-wrapper", ($form['field_camp_location3'])));
    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand("#edit-field-camp-cid3-wrapper", ($form['field_camp_cid3'])));
    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand("#edit-field-camp-location4-wrapper", ($form['field_camp_location4'])));
    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand("#edit-field-camp-cid4-wrapper", ($form['field_camp_cid4'])));
    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand("#edit-field-camp-location5-wrapper", ($form['field_camp_location5'])));
    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand("#edit-field-camp-cid5-wrapper", ($form['field_camp_cid5'])));
    return $response;   

}
```

So this is my code.

I 'am populating content based on the selected location.

What is happening is, whenever i upload a file on my file file $lid1 value becomes NULL but the dropdown value has not change.

Comment: Kindly show us what you tried.

Comment: @A Ajay Reddy I've updated my post